# How to use @graphy npm package in angular application?

Tags: angular

I need to use lib to parse RDF on the browser side. I am trying to use Graphy https://github.com/blake-regalia/graphy.js as it seems to have promising benchmarks. However, I have no idea how to use it in Angular. Author claims that it should fine with Webpack, but it seams that is not that straightforward (to me at least) as with other NPM libs.

What I did:

```
 npm install --save graphy
```

and

```
import ttlReader from '@graphy/content.ttl.read';
....
    const reader = ttlReader();
    reader.read(graphContent);
    reader.on('data', console.log);
```

But that ends with

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    js index.js:43
    Webpack 20
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        node_modules
        __webpack_require__
        ts
        __webpack_require__
        ts
        __webpack_require__
        ts
        __webpack_require__
        ts
        __webpack_require__
        0
        __webpack_require__
        checkDeferredModules
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
```

How can I use that library in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try updating some webpack configs.

Try updating node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js

Almost at the end of the file you will find `plugins` and `node`, update the value of `node` (which is `false`) to be `{crypto: true, stream: true, fs: 'empty', net: 'empty'}`.

You can also add a postinstall script in the package.json to updated that file after the package installation.